# How to catch a key event when JFrame is minimized?

Tags: java, swing, location, point

I am learning java as a beginner and I was tasked to make an auto-click tool. I used JFrame as an Interface but now I'm stuck with this problem:
- I want to get location of pointer related to screen after user clicked a button (Ctrl for example). I added a button on JFrame, click it and the JFrame will be minimized so user can move the pointer around desktop. 
- Whenever user pressed Ctrl key, I should println the x,y position of the pointer at that time.
- I've been swum around to find a solution, but it seemed like my brain couldn't catch up.

It would be a very appreciation if anyone can provide me a simple example. Thanks.
My idea so far:

```
     private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
     this.setState(JFrame.ICONIFIED);
     this.addKeyListener(this);
     }

     @Override
     public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
     if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.CTRL_DOWN_MASK) {
                PointerInfo a = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo();
                Point b = a.getLocation();
                int x = (int) b.getX();
                int y = (int) b.getY();
                System.out.println(x + ":" + y);
            }
    }
```

Comment: Questions for pointers to existing documentation are not appropriate, as a rule. Please show the efforts you have made yourself so far.

Comment: @FelixFrank added. I run it and nothing happened even when I maximize the frame again and hit Ctrl.

Answer (score 2):

> I want to get location of pointer related to screen after user clicked a button..

On button click:

- Hide the frame.
- Get a screenshot of the entire desktop.
- Show the screenshot in a `JLabel` in a `JWindow`
- Add a `MouseListener` to the label.
- Get the `Point` from the `MouseEvent`.

E.G. similar to what is shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11007422/418556).

[image]