# Swing - Transparent decorated JFrame doesn't trigger mouseClicked()/mousePressed() event

Tags: java, swing, mouseevent

Inspired by this answer:

[how to obtain mouse click coordinates outside my window in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2419555/how-to-obtain-mouse-click-coordinates-outside-my-window-in-java#answer-2420820)

I have implemented a Java Swing screen color picker with an almost-transparent JFrame covering all the screen. The R, G, B values are shown in three `JTextfield` and when I click somewhere, I want to see this point's color shown in the table as a new row of data.

You can see that color codes are shown and changing, so `mouseMoved()` events are triggered, but `mouseClicked()`/`mousePressed()` event are not. I am confused. I am with Windows 10.

Code here:

```
import static java.awt.GraphicsDevice.WindowTranslucency.TRANSLUCENT;

import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GraphicsDevice;
import java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.event.MouseInputListener;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class ColorPicker extends JFrame{

    private static JTextField fieldRed;
    private static JTextField fieldGreen;
    private static JTextField fieldBlue;
    private Robot robot;
    private static JTable table;
    public JFrame helperScreen;
    public ColorPicker() {
        initialize();
    }

    private void initialize() {
        setAlwaysOnTop(false);
        setAutoRequestFocus(false);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.HIDE_ON_CLOSE);
        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

//        try {
//            UIManager.setLookAndFeel("javax.swing.plaf.nimbus.NimbusLookAndFeel");
//        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException
//                | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException e) {
//            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
//            e.printStackTrace();
//        }

        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;

        table = new JTable();
        DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel();
        model.setColumnIdentifiers(new String[] {"Keys", "Values", "Color"});
        table.setModel(model);
        table.setDefaultRenderer(Object.class, new ColorRenderer());
        JScrollPane pane = new JScrollPane(table);
        pane.setBounds(0, 0, 500, 500);

        c.gridheight = 1;
        c.gridwidth = 3;
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 0;

        add(pane, c);

        c = new GridBagConstraints();
        c.gridheight = 1;
        c.gridwidth = 1;
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 1;
        c.weightx = 0.5;
        fieldRed = new JTextField();
        fieldRed.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 25));
        add(fieldRed, c);

        c.gridx = 1;
        fieldGreen = new JTextField();
        fieldGreen.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 25));
        add(fieldGreen, c);

        c.gridx = 2;
        fieldBlue = new JTextField();
        fieldBlue.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 25));
        add(fieldBlue, c);

        Dimension screen = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        helperScreen = new JFrame();
        helperScreen.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        helperScreen.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
        helperScreen.setOpacity(0.05f);
        helperScreen.setPreferredSize(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize());
        helperScreen.setBounds(0, 0, (int)screen.getWidth(), (int)screen.getHeight());
        helperScreen.addMouseMotionListener(new ScreenMouseListener());
        helperScreen.setVisible(true);

        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
     // Determine if the GraphicsDevice supports translucency.
        GraphicsEnvironment ge =  GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
        GraphicsDevice gd = ge.getDefaultScreenDevice();

        //If translucent windows aren't supported, exit.
        if (!gd.isWindowTranslucencySupported(TRANSLUCENT)) {
            System.err.println("Translucency is not supported");
            System.exit(0);
        }

        JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);

        ColorPicker picker = new ColorPicker();
    }

    private class ColorRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {

        @Override
        public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus,
                int row, int column) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (column == 2 && value instanceof Color) {
                Component label = super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);
                label.setBackground((Color)value);
                JLabel label2 = (JLabel)label;
                label2.setText("");
                return label2;
            } else {
                setBackground(Color.WHITE);
                setText(value.toString());
                return this;
            }
        }

    }

    private class ScreenMouseListener implements MouseInputListener {
        Object[] row = new Object[3];
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            try {
                robot = new Robot();
            } catch (AWTException eg) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                eg.printStackTrace();
            }
            Point point = ((MouseEvent)e).getLocationOnScreen();
            int x = point.x;
            int y = point.y;
            helperScreen.setVisible(false);
            System.out.println("Mouse Pressed at x: " + x + " y: " + y);
            Color c = robot.getPixelColor(x, y);

            row[0] = x;
            row[1] = y;
            row[2] = c;

            ((DefaultTableModel)(table.getModel())).addRow(row);
            ((DefaultTableModel)(table.getModel())).fireTableDataChanged();
            helperScreen.setVisible(true);
        }
        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            try {
                robot = new Robot();
            } catch (AWTException eg) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                eg.printStackTrace();
            }
            Point point = ((MouseEvent)e).getLocationOnScreen();
            int x = point.x;
            int y = point.y;
            helperScreen.setVisible(false);
            System.out.println("Mouse Pressed at x: " + x + " y: " + y);
            Color c = robot.getPixelColor(x, y);

            row[0] = x;
            row[1] = y;
            row[2] = c;

            ((DefaultTableModel)(table.getModel())).addRow(row);
            ((DefaultTableModel)(table.getModel())).fireTableDataChanged();
            helperScreen.setVisible(true);

        }
        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
        @Override
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
        @Override
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
        @Override
        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
        @Override
        public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
            try {
                robot = new Robot();
            } catch (AWTException eg) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                eg.printStackTrace();
            }
            Point point = ((MouseEvent)e).getLocationOnScreen();
            int x = point.x;
            int y = point.y;
            helperScreen.setVisible(false);
            Color c = robot.getPixelColor(x, y);

            fieldRed.setText(Integer.toString(c.getRed()));
            fieldGreen.setText(Integer.toString(c.getGreen()));
            fieldBlue.setText(Integer.toString(c.getBlue()));
            helperScreen.setVisible(true);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: *"Transparent decorated JFrame doesn't trigger mouseClicked()/mousePressed() event"* That's most likely a security measure to help avoid creation of a mouse logger in Java. Damn good thing as well. As an alternative, grab a screenshot and ask the user to select a color from that. Here is [an example of selecting an area on-screen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11007422/418556) (a rectangle) that uses this approach.

Comment: seems like as your Robot is CPU & GPU killer, each of public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) { generating sets of quite hard events, notice from every pixel

Comment: Hmm. @Andrew, so "that's a feature, not a bug". First time in my life.

Comment: @mKorbel that's what it should be, isn't it? Moving every pixel generates an event, just like color picker in Photoshop. I doubt if we could improve a little...

Comment: @AndrewThompson I wonder how I can see the part defining of this strange behaviour in JDK.